# Searching for partial path\filename in bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Ok, so I've been bating (hehe) my head against a wall here.
I am looking for an option/code that would allow me to search for a partial path and/or filename from a .bat script that I would export to an outside file.

Now, "search", "export" and "outside file" is something I am fine with. The part that is giving me a headache is the "partial".

To elaborate.
I am looking for a folder called DATA and a file called userinfo.txt inside DATA.
Those are constant. So the path I have is DATA\userinfo.txt
I am also 99% certain that this folder will be in D:\ but thats not a concern right now. Where ever it is I'll find it.
But I cannot figure out how to look for a partial path\filename for the life of me.

Reason I have specified that DATA\userinfo.txt is a constant is due to other folders ability to be named arbitrarily. So in my below example 01-12-2016 does not have to be named according to that convention. For USA it would most likely be named 12-01-2016. It is also sometimes named 20161201 or 20160112 or on top of all that has a letter prefix such as d01-12-2016. On that note DATA is always DATA, which is why I said DATA is constant in my search. Another thing that will be the same is the grandparent folder. When i say "same" i mean "shared" between the two applications. It does not mean it will always be named "program" as in my example below.

Googling this and using things I know has got me nowhere.

Reason I cannot simply use

```
where /r d: userinfo.txt
```

is that that specific command will return hundreds of results as there is a userinfo.txt created for every.single.day the program was running and is stored separately.

**Alternatively** - if there would be a way to comb trough those hundreds of results and find the matching part that would also resolve my issue.

This however brings up another headache as there is usually more than one program with this exact file.

so in the example of

```
d:\users\path\program\storage\01-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\01-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\storage\02-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\02-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\storage\03-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\03-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\storage\04-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\04-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\storage\05-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\05-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\storage\06-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\06-12-2016\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\storage\data\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\data\userinfo.txt
```

Note: storage, otherstorage, storageother, storage2, storagegh are all arbitrary names as these folders are named accoring to end-user wishes.
I would want to export two separate variables for

```
d:\users\path\program\storage
```

and

```
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage
```

I would also need to do this for \data\userinfo.txt

So if searching for \data\userinfo.txt it would return

```
d:\users\path\program\storage\data\userinfo.txt
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\data\userinfo.txt
```

I would also want to isolate both

```
d:\users\path\program\storage
```

and

```
d:\users\path\program\otherstorage
```

and use it as (separate) local variables.

I would need to note that installing/downloading any external scripting tools/aids would not be a suitable solution as I work on **a lot** of computers, most of which I do not have internet access and/or sufficient permissions for external downloads/installations so anything that is not integrated into the bat and needs to be imported separately is a bad idea.

Also, I am working on Windows XP SP3 but I would need this bat to be able to run on XP SP2, XP SP3, Windows 7, Windows 10, Windows NT, Windows 2000.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please note that

```
d:\users\path\program
```

would also be an acceptable variable. In this case I would manually amend the remainder of the path or would rely on end-user (my coworkers) input to complete the path correctly. The last has proven to be a fools errand.

The way that I've been handling it until now is to look for a .exe that I KNOW will be in both folders. This is a part of my code below edited to match the current example.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
echo Program will now look for program.exe and programgh.exe. Please input, when asked, matching part of the path for these files.
echo Example:
echo d:\users\path\program\storage\bin\program.exe
echo d:\users\path\program\otherstorage\bin\programgh.exe
echo In above example matching part is d:\users\path\program so you would enter that when prompted
echo Please do not input the last pathing mark: \ (backslash)
echo -------------searching---------------
::I am exporting errors to nul as I don't want them to be spammed by errors and other data that they would think is their fault
where /r c: program*.exe 2>nul
where /r d: program*.exe 2>nul
where /r e: program*.exe 2>nul
where /r f: program*.exe 2>nul
set /p dualpath="Please enter matching paths for program folder: "
```

After that I would proceed to work with %dualpath% variable.

As it usually happens (to me at least) most people would just copy the example path without taking a look at what the program has spat out and would be confused as to why the program did not work. Either that or would copy everything up to program.exe and programgh.exe - including the otherstorage\bin\ without noticing that \storage\ and \otherstorage\ do not match.

I think this now covers all the comments or additional questions and clarifies a bit better what I need.  Thank you all for help so far and I hope that this is easier to understand.

Comment: So basically, you want to find the common root directory, is that correct? Or do you want to get the grandparent directory/-ies of `userinfo.txt`? You say that `DATA` is constant, but this does not comply with your examples, which contain date-value directories instead, so please clarify...

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S "userinfo.txt"') do for /D %%D in ("%%F\..\..") do echo(%%~D` should return `D:\users\path\programs\storage` and `D:\users\path\programs\storage2` in your situation...

Comment: @aschipfl Yeah, I realize that it might be slightly confusing in what I've written. I probably lost focus somewhere along the line. Sorry.
I'll edit my post with more information

Comment: Wow, that has grown to a monster question. You should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @lotpings I'd be open to a book on "how to organize and summarize your thoughts"
On hat note, you do have a point, lets start over xD
Editing

Comment: I may have got lost on the way, but I thought my answer meets your requirements?

Comment: @lotpings I'm sorry, just noticed that the last answer was yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your intention right, the following script should do what you want:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\" & rem "D:\", "D:\users",..., or "D:\users\path\program"
set "_FILE=userinfo.txt"

rem // Initialise index:
set /A "INDEX=1"
rem // Search for the specified file in the given root directory:
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S "%_ROOT%\%_FILE%"') do (
    rem // Iterate once over the grandparent directory itself:
    for /D %%D in ("%%F\..\..") do (
        rem // Resolve the path of the grantparent directory;
        set "ITEM=%%~fD"
        rem // Initialise flag (non-empty means not yet stored):
        set "FLAG=#"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with exclamation marks:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Iterate over all currently stored grantparent paths:
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%V in ('2^> nul set $ARRAY[') do (
            rem // Clear flag in case current grandparent has already been stored:
            if /I "!%%V!"=="!ITEM!" set "FLAG="
        )
        rem // Check flag:
        if defined FLAG (
            rem // Flag is empty, so current grandparent needs to be stored:
            set "$ARRAY[!INDEX!]=!ITEM!"
            rem // Transfer stored grandparent over localisation barrier:
            for /F "delims=" %%E in ("$ARRAY[!INDEX!]=!ITEM!") do (
                endlocal
                set "%%E"
            )
            rem // Increment index
            set /A "INDEX+=1"
        ) else endlocal
    )
)
rem // Retrieving final count of grandparent directories:
set /A "INDEX-=1"

rem // Return stored grandparent paths:
set $ARRAY[

endlocal
exit /B
```

This should return `D:\users\path\programs\otherstorage` and `D:\users\path\programs\storage` in your situation, which are stored in the variables `$ARRAY[1]` and `$ARRAY[2]`, respectively. Due to the array-style variables, this approach is flexible enough to cover also cases where more than two grandparent directories are present.

Comment: Just a quick clarification, why would I want a `else endlocal` after index increment. And why would I want/need `exit /b`. I am intending to keep working with these variables after they are defined. The script does work and does exactly what I need it to; even more so thank you. If you could just clarify these two points so I understand what it does in full. Thank you

Comment: There is a `setlocal` command before the `if` query, the related `endlocal` is in the body of `if`; `else endlocal` just ensures that the `setlocal` localisation is ended also in case the `if` condition is not fulfilled. The `exit /B` is actually not needed here as the script is exited anyway when its end is reached; this is just a "habbit" of me...

Comment: Ok, I saw two `setlocal` and three `endlocal` so I was confused slightly. Ok, so the `exit /b` is just the "usual" `exit` at the end of the script. If i remove it I would be able to keep working on the script after the variables are defined? Oh, and thanks for the remarks in the code, very helpful.

Comment: If you want the variables to be available after the script terminates, you need to remove the initial `setlocal` command line and the final `endlocal`; note that the variables are only available in the same `cmd` (command prompt) instance in which the script was running before...

Comment: I think Im not explaining myself right there but Im understanding what you are saying. Thank you for your help again :-)

Answer (score 1):

If a Windows `cmd` command allows wildcards in a [(partially or fully qualified) path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths) then wildcards must be used only in the [path leaf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) (i.e. the last item or container in the path). However, you could apply [`findstr` regex](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to narrow command output e.g. as follows:

```
where /r d:\ userinfo.txt | findstr /I "\\storage2*\\data\\userinfo.txt"
```

above command wold narrow output to paths *ending* with `\storage\data\userinfo.txt` and `\storage2\data\userinfo.txt`

Another example - narrow output to paths *ending* with `\storageX\data\userinfo.txt` where `X` is either nothing or any decimal cipher `[0-9]`:

```
dir /B /S d:\userinfo.txt | findstr /I "\\storage[0-9]*\\data\\userinfo.txt"
```

Put the paths to environment variables (with `_var` prefix for easier next identification), e.g. `_varstorage`, `_varstorage2`, …

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
  dir /B /S "d:\userinfo.txt" ^| findstr /I "\\storage[0-9]*\\data\\userinfo.txt"') do (
    for /D %%D in ("%%~dpF..") do (
        set "_var%%~nxD=%%~fD"
        rem             %%~fD        path
        rem      %%~nxD              last item in above path
        rem  _var                    variable name prefix
    )
)
rem show result:
set _var
```

See also next `%%~nxD` and `%%~D` explanation:  [Command Line arguments (Parameters): Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. As pointed out by another comment my question contains some confusing information so I will edit the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your above sample this batch

```
@Echo off
Set Search=\\data\\userinfo.txt
pushd "D:\Users\path\program
For /f "Delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S/A-D userinfo.txt ^|findstr "%Search%$"'
) Do Call :Sub "%%~fA" "%%~dpA.."
Popd
Goto :Eof
:Sub FullName DrivePath
Echo Found  %~nx1
Echo in     %~dp1
Echo Granny %~nx2
Set "Granny=%~nx2"
Echo in     %~dp2
Echo -------
```

Should give this output (only partially tested)

```
Found  userinfo.txt
in     D:\Users\path\program\storage\data\
Granny storage
in     D:\Users\path\program\
-------
Found  userinfo.txt
in     D:\Users\path\program\storage2\data\
Granny storage2
in     D:\Users\path\program\
-------
```

The backslash in `Search` has to be doubled as it is an escape char for findstr

Comment: So right now this works if/when I change 'pushd "D:\Users\path\program' to 'd:' since I dont actually know what the path is and need to search entire d: and often other drives so I would need to >nul error output.  Also - this is quite advanced for me xD   So any help as to how to assign the "Granny" output as a variable would be welcome.

Comment: I added a `Set "Granny=%~nx2"` but since the for is still iterating it will be overwritten by the next find. So you should insert your code at this point. I'd be glad if [you'd accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)